# How to fix ,End of file expected error in settings.json file?

Tags: css, json, sass, visual-studio-code, live-sass-compiler

So I installed the Live sass compiler extension but it was not working. I went to its settings and nothing was there. So I went to its MD file on copied its settings in my settings.json file. But after that, I am getting this error -

This is the code -

```
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
 
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": null
    },

    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "savePath": "/dist/css"
    },

    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "savePath": "~/../css/"
    }
]
```

and this is the error -

`End of file expected. jsonc [1, 35]`

Also, I am new to stack overflow! So pardon my Naivety.

Comment: Is that all in your file?

Comment: Ya and actually I pasted this from the documents of the extension. My settings.json file was empty. Not the defaultsettings.json tho but this one!

Answer (score 4):

A JSON file must start with array(`[`) or object(`{`). Maybe you should have pasted it inside your file somewhere.

```
{
  "settings": {
    // maybe somewhere like here
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: But why do I have to paste anything at all? Shouldn't the live sass compiler extension already have these settings in place? It seems like the extension is empty or do I have errors in my defaultsettings.json file?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question about what you installed and what you did. My answer is just about the error msg.

Comment: Ya thank you, I did it your way and now the error is gone now. But the problem is the live sass compiler extension is not generating the output file anywhere !! I thought this error was the reason but now that it is solved. I don't know why it's not working? Edit : Also, I can't upvote your answer need 15 rep points for that.

Comment: Which document are you looking at?

Comment: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Comment: Did you press `Watch Sass` button at the bottom to compile it?

Comment: yes of course,  I have also tried reinstalling the vs code but nothing seems to work. And I just open the defaultsettings.json file and it is showing me 6 similar errors. How can I post the screenshot here ?

Comment: Editing your question will be better

Comment: I posted in the answer 

Comment: Those are warnings, and you should show the warning lines at least..

Comment: But I am not allowed to embed images in my questions!

Comment: "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": null, warning - Value is not accepted. Valid values: "PowerShell", "Command Prompt", "JavaScript Debug Terminal".